# How to play flash games in android

Tags: android, flash

I have developed a game in flash now i want to run that flash file in android os.
i have followed several questions here but unable to get the solution please help me

Comment: Please improve your question. What have you tried and how did it not work?

Answer (score 0):

App developed in AS3 can be run in Adobe AIR environment. You need Adobe AIR on your device and I suppose that an app needs to be optimized for AIR.

Of course you can also run it in browser if you have flash player, but it will have really bad user experience.